# System always boots to grub prompt

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, 18.04

After installing a fresh copy of Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop, I am shown the grub prompt at boot.

I've tried:

- boot-repair tool within liveUSB: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/6Q3ndws93b/
- Re-install grub from liveUSB: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GrCKTgbjRm/
- manually booting ( https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/j89ZK9Jgdx/ ) and using boot-repair ( https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/knYGTtwkWz/ )

But I am still shown the grub prompt at each boot.

How can I fix grub so that it automatically starts the installed system?

Comment: I fixed it by setting BIOS parameter "UEFI/Legacy Boot" to "UEFI Only" and "CSM Support" to Yes.

Comment: @Jos Doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: What brand/model system. Some require work arounds. But you are showing grub entry, not typical Ubuntu entry. If not from another install like Debian, grub is not correct.  I installed 18.10 and got a similar grub entry, but it used my default /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg file, not the /EFI/grub/grub.cfg file for 18.10. You do not have /EFI/ubuntu folder in ESP? If not copy all of /EFI/grub to /EFI/ubuntu. You may only need grub.cfg for it to work. Please post this bug, if grub UEFI entry is from Ubuntu, not another install: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1775743

Comment: @oldfred - custom build, had no /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg ( https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/82bFbST6xw/ ). That ticket mentioned grub-efi-amd64 was missing and sure enough installing it fixes my issue! Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I needed to install `grub-efi-amd64`, system then booted as expected.

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1775743#yui_3_10_3_1_1531236190615_547 and comment #21 by Jean-Baptiste Lallement (jibel)

Comment: There is now a separate bug for 18.04. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1781042 Please add to it, to get it prioritized.  Seems strange that installer updates install a "bad" version of grub that installs to /EFI/grub, but manually booting and updating grub works as /EFI/ubuntu?

Comment: How can i install grub-efi-amd64?

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. Solved by manual partitioning of hard disk within installer.
I chose partition1 /dev/sda1 type efi size 1023 type boot. Partition 2 type swap size 2xRAM e.g 16384. Partition 3 ext4 / remaining. But i believe wher it all ends in tears is that one needs to select at bottom of screen boot=/dev/sda1 NOT boot=/dev/sda

Answer (score 0):

Set your boot mode to UEFI, if it doesn't work, try install again with UEFI and be sure to set the partition to GPT rather than MBR to avoid these kind of things!

Comment: Did a fresh install, confirmed GPT ( https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7q5qB7PPhd/ ), still no good

Comment: Did it work after installing grub-efi-amd64 ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem: after installing Ubuntu I was left with an empty grub prompt. 
I'm dual booting with Windows 10. Both the ssd on which I have the Windows and the EFI partition, and the harddisk on which I have Ubuntu are partitioned with GPT. Bios is set to boot in UEFI mode, with secure boot and fast boot both turned off.
I've installed grub-efi-amd64, but it changed nothing. 
After installing Ubuntu, I could boot either operating system only by pressing F12 to access the boot menu, from where I could choose either Windows or Ubuntu, both of which continue booting normally from here, the Ubuntu menu entry leading to a working grub. 
At the end, I've had to edit my EFI entries so that Windows would be the first one, so that at least now Windows loads directly, without any further intervention during the boot process. If I want to enter Ubuntu, I have to go through the bios boot menu.

Comment: Would you mind editing your answer to a) remove the problem statement and b) tell us what exactly you edited?

Answer (score 0):

None of below answers worked for me. I just decided to reinstall ubuntu(but keep windows) and actually problem solved after reinstalling ubuntu!