# 18.04 dual boot showing grub2 manual

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, 18.04, grub-efi

Did a fresh install of 18.04 alongside Windows 10 (UEFI). Now my system boots only into grub2 commandline.

I am able to boot into both windows by executing

```
chainloader **(hd0,gpt1)**/efi/Microsoft/bootmfgw.efi
```

and ubuntu by executing

```
set prefix=(hd0,gpt6)/boot/grub
set root=**(hd0,gpt6)**
insmod linux
insmod normal
normal
```

I ran grub-install, boot repair several times after booting into ubuntu, but to no effect.
I still keep booting into grub commandline.

Any help is appreciated.
Boot repair pastebin - http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/64X9XmshBJ

Screenshot of gparted:

[image]

I have tried these, and it did not work:

- grub-install with grub-efi-amd4
- grub install from live usb
- boot-repair from live usb or ubuntu
- fresh install of 18.04 again lands in grub manual

Comment: once you are in Ubuntu with above commands, can you provide a pic after opening "GParted"

Comment: @PRATAP Screenshot of gparted
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dX_aCj9LK9bi8XuKO9SVLndlCUeOuaCL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: also dump of one of the boot-repair attempts - http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/64X9XmshBJ/

Comment: can you click on sda2 "red color alert" and paste the error?

Comment: It says warning ! -
Unable to detect file system! Possible reasons are:
- The file system is damaged
- The file system is unknown to GParted
- There is no file system available (unformatted)
- The device entry /dev/sda2 is missing

Comment: what is sdb? are you using that for data?

Comment: /sdb is my 2 TB hard disk with ntfs partitions for storage and games.
/sda is the SSD

Comment: Ok, have you tried Boot-Repair with live session? that could solve the thing. if not, you may need to delete that partition sda2 red color alert. First try Boot-Repair with live session.

Comment: Or you can first try the answer in this question. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042813/installation-of-windows-10-ubuntu-18-04-ubuntu-18-04-windows-10

Comment: @PRATAP should I install the grub in /sda or /sda1(where my existing efi files are) ?

Comment: you should select /sda for grub install command. sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sda

Comment: Error on your sda2 is normal. It really should not be an error as it is a required partition by Windows. But gparted sees it as unformatted so flags as an error. Since it has a valid GUID for Microsoft Reserved partition, gparted should know it is valid. Have you tried a full uninstall/reinstall of grub using Boot-Repair? See this thread. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053895/system-always-boots-to-grub-prompt?noredirect=1#comment1722812_1053895

Comment: @jayendra.rakesh please ignore my comment where i suggested to delete sda2. I agree with Mr. oldfred.

Comment: See this. It looks like they rolled out newer grub with bug that supposedly is fixed in 18.10. Ubuntu 18.10 Cosmic installed /EFI/grub
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1775743 Also: 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2396042 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053895/system-always-boots-to-grub-prompt?noredirect=1#comment1722812_1053895

Comment: @oldfred Thank you, copying the grub.cfg file worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using windows 10 on sda3
and you install and boot ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo blkid
 (read uuid from /dev/sda3, used below as uuid_read_above)

sudo nano /etc/default/grub
 (add line to the end of the file:)
    GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="part_msdos"
sudo update-grub

sudo nano /etc/grub.d/40_custom
 (add these lines to the end of the file:)
    menuentry "Windows 10" {
     insmod ntfs
     set root='(hd0,3)'
     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set uuid_read_above
     ntldr /bootmgr
     chainloader +1     
    }
sudo update-grub

sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

exit and boot from hdd, should see menu with "Windows 10"

[boot](/questions/tagged/boot) [dual-boot](/questions/tagged/dual-boot) [grub2](/questions/tagged/grub2) [uefi](/questions/tagged/uefi) [18.04](/questions/tagged/18.04) [grub-efi](/questions/tagged/grub-efi) [grub-pc](/questions/tagged/grub-pc) [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10) [ntfs](/questions/tagged/ntfs)